# How to reload .bashrc settings without logging out and back in again?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, reload, profile

If I make changes to `.bashrc`, how do I reload it without logging out and back in?

Answer (score 3473, accepted):

You can enter the long form command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or you can use the shorter version of the command:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: i seem to keep having to do this every time i open terminal... is there a way to automate it?

Comment: This is not exactly the same as logging in and back out. Say you had the following line in .bashrc: `export PATH=$PATH:foo`, and then you change it to `export PATH=$PATH:bar`. If you log in and back out, only `bar` will be in the PATH, but if you do what you suggest, both `foo` and `bar` will be in the PATH. Do you know of a way around this?

Comment: what is that "command"? I did "man command", but it has no info about it. Searching gives no info either http://www.yandex.com/yandsearch?text=linux+man+source&lr=87 . Is it a command at all?

Comment: @gekannt - if you do "type source" you'll see that source isn't a normal command but rather a "shell builtin" - this means you won't find an executable for it somewhere in the file system, e.g. in /usr/bin, instead it is implemented as part of the shell. So if you do "man bash" and search for the section "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" and then search for "source" you'll find a good explanation of what source does (and if you understand fork as well then it should become clear why source is a builtin rather than a command).

Comment: @HighCommander4 - a very unsatisfactory way to sort of do what you want is to do "bash -l" however this actually creates a new subshell and when you logout you'll return to the enclosing shell where "foo" is still in PATH. If you're just interested in PATH, you could do "unset PATH" and reconstruct it from scratch, but probably easier/safer is to do "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin" before sourcing your .bashrc. How the PATH variable is built up on login is actually reasonably complex, involving input at the very least from login (see "man login") and /etc/profile (see "man bash").

Comment: @Alex you can automate it by adding the line ~/.bashrc into ~/.bash_profile, though I don't know if this is a good practice.

Comment: I would also recommend creating an alias (which you could store in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases) that opens .bashrc, and reloads it after the editor exits. You can do it by combining two commands in an alias, for example like so (if vim is your preferred editor, otherwise swap it out to something else):
```alias editbashrc='vim ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc'```. This will make the editing much smoother, since you don't need to think about the reloading, after doing the edit, if using the custom alias.

Comment: It will affect **only** the current terminal.

Comment: I'm using this alias to edit bashrc for all users: ***alias bashrc="sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc; source /etc/bash.bashrc"***

Comment: I think the answer below from @WhoSayIn should be preferred over this to prevent the PATH problem discussed above: 

`exec bash`

Comment: Seems `source ~/.bashrc` this throw out of current python virtualenv.

Comment: This will only be valid for current terminal, whether using "fresh start" exec bash, or "ad-hoc" source ~/.bashrc. I am currently working from home, I want to be able to SSH in to my remote host and have all updated settings without executing these commands each time I make a new SSH connection. I cannot access office to perform on-site log out/restart, due to practical and bureaucratic reasons. Any suggestions?

Comment: @HighCommander4 another way of ensuring that both `foo` and `bar` are in the path if `PATH=$PATH:foo` is already entered is to add `PATH=$PATH:foo:bar`. This should include both. Ideally, you would want to go in and erase the first declaration, but as you point out, it is overwritten anyway. Erasing just makes it cleaner and supports readability.

Comment: @MahNas92 If you open a new terminal, you do not need to do anything. Once it is sourced, any terminal opened will automatically include it. For previously opened terminals, it needs to be sourced from each. The easiest option, imo, is to broadcast all and reset or source.

Comment: This seems to work great for my purposes. I haven't noticed any edge cases yet. Will update here if so. Thank you!

Comment: You can also add a line to your `.bashrc`: `alias RELOAD=". ~/.bashrc"`

Answer (score 395):

Or you could use:

```
exec bash
```

This does the same thing, and is easier to remember (at least for me).

The `exec` command completely replaces the shell process by running the specified command-line. In our example, it replaces whatever the current shell is with a fresh instance of `bash` (with the updated configuration files).

Comment: Could you please explain the difference of `source .bashrc` command and `exec bash`?

Comment: @muradin, `source` is a built-in shell command that executes the content of the file passed as argument, _in the current shell_. So in your example, it executes .bashrc file in the current shell.

And `exec` command replaces the shell with a given program, in your example, it replaces your shell with bash (with the updated configuration files)

Comment: It's great especially because the bashrc may be updated either in `/etc` or `/home` directory, and we don't need to care about this.

Comment: In my hyper-specific circumstance, this totally rocked. My Dockerfile executes an install script that modifies .bashrc. I then need that to reload, but `. ~/.bashrc` will execute in `dash` rather than `bash`, so there is an error because `shopt` is missing. `source` isn't found from the shell, so that solution is out as well. I tried this and the docker image built smoothly!

Comment: For CentOS7 and with helper bash configs, this was most helpful. Doing `. ~/.bashrc` did not reload my custom aliases file.

Comment: Elegant, but "does the same thing" is not entirely correct. `source ~/.bashrc` will preserve your _entire_ shell environment (though likely modified by the sourcing of `~/.bashrc`), whereas `exec bash` will only preserve your current shell's _environment variables_ (any ad-hoc changes to the current shell in terms of shell variables, function, options are lost). Depending on your needs, one or the other approach may be preferred.

Comment: @mklement0, thanks for the detailed information. This solution would work in many cases but I guess you may need to use -source- in situations like you mentioned.

Comment: @SEoF, when you say "bash inception" and if you are thinking what I think you are thinking, I must say that you are wrong. Unlike the movie, you don't keep on going into bash from bash when you repeatedly do `exec bash`. The `exec` command *replaces* the shell with the program, in our case, bash. So, there is always one instance of bash in existence in the terminal.

Comment: Some specific examples of the kind of surprise [@mklement0 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/2518150#comment57870320_9584378):  Your `pushd` / `popd` directory stack will be erased (except for the CWD), and your `PS1` prompt will be reset. Some dev environments, like Python's `virtualenv` / `venv`, alter your `PATH` and other variables, and put the name of the active environment in your `PS1` prompt. After `exec bash`, the environment variables are still active, but the visual indicator in the `PS1` prompt is gone. Also, cleanup functions like `deactivate` have vanished.

Comment: This works for my Cygwin + win7. Thanks! Typing this faster that typing . ~/.bashrc

Comment: Will this work for another session I open after running 'exec bash' in my current session ?

Comment: just to add, use: exec $SHELL -l; as $SHELL returns bash in this instance.

Comment: This worked. Super nice, short, solid. `source` did not work for some reason.

Comment: That worked perfectly for me when the source option wasn't working, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, that way I don't have to restart terminal and use bash whenever absolutely necessary! Thanks again

Comment: @whosayin thx! this just helped me with executing ansible-playbooks that were no longer accepting arguments that had worked previously.

Comment: The issue here is that you lose your entire command history. (The commands entered from that terminal, not the global history, which is practically useless anyway, imo.)

Comment: Nice, I've been using `source` for years, but I've noticed that if I `source` my `rc` file multiple times it'd take longer with every iteration. I'm guessing there's something stacking in the background. Anyway I've replaced my old "source shell" alias with `alias ss="exec ${SHELL}"` and things behave as expected now.

Answer (score 177):

To **complement and contrast** the two most popular answers, [`. ~/.bashrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518150/45375) and [`exec bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9584378/45375):

Both solutions *effectively* reload `~/.bashrc`, but there are differences:

- `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` will ***preserve* your current shell session**:

  - Except for the modifications that reloading `~/.bashrc` into the current shell (*sourcing*) makes, **the *current shell process and its state* are *preserved***, which includes environment variables, shell variables, shell options, shell functions, and command history.
- `exec bash`, or, more robustly, `exec "$BASH"`<sup>[1]</sup>,
  will ***replace* your current shell** with a new instance, and therefore ***only* preserve your current shell's *environment variables*** (including ones you've defined ad hoc, in-session).

  - In other words: Any ad-hoc changes to the current shell in terms of shell variables, shell functions, shell options, command history are lost.

Depending on your needs, one or the other approach may be preferred.

---

Note: The above applies analogously to *other shells* too:

- To apply the `exec` approach to *whatever your default shell is*, use `exec $SHELL`
- Similarly, the sourcing approach requires you to know and specify the name of the shell-specific initialization file; e.g., for `zsh`: `. ~/.zshrc`

---

<sup>[1] `exec bash` could in theory execute a *different* `bash` executable than the one that started the current shell, if it happens to exist in a directory listed earlier in the `$PATH`. Since special variable `$BASH` always contains the full path of the executable that started the current shell, `exec "$BASH"` is guaranteed to use the *same* executable.

A note re `"..."` around `$BASH`: double-quoting ensures that the variable value is used as-is, without interpretation by Bash; if the value has no embedded spaces or other shell metacharacters (which is likely in this case), you don't strictly need double quotes, but using them is a good habit to form.</sup>

Comment: You answered my question before I could ask it. This is good to know; I often set my CLASSPATH for a single session.

Comment: So even if I call exec "$BASH" will the variables that .bashrc sets be found in the shell I open next (using the same executable as my current session) ?

Comment: @nitinr708: Yes, `exec $BASH` will source `~/.bashrc`, so you'll see its changes to the shell environment in the new session.

Comment: This is why I use `broadcast all` + source. Best of both worlds, imo.

Comment: @i_want_more_edits: `$SHELL` reflects whatever shell is the current user's _default shell_, which may or may not be Bash.

Comment: @mklement0 so if I called a `/path/to/different/executable/bash`, `$BASH` whould contain that path, while `$SHELL` would not mind and contain the default shell, right?

Comment: @i_want_more_edits: Correct.

Comment: To add on the simplicity of the `exec $BASH` command, this command also works inside the automated shell scripts where we don't know user's actual shell type i.e. BASH/ZSH/FISH etc. If we use `source ~/.bashrc` inside the shell script then we also need to add an explicit check to find the user's shell type before you can run the `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`or `~/.config/fish/config.fish` command.

Answer (score 57):

Someone edited my answer to add incorrect English, but here was the original, which is inferior to the accepted answer.

```
. .bashrc
```

Comment: This will only work if your current directory is actually your home directory.  The following will work:

. ~/.bashrc

Comment: What makes this work? What is actually happening when I do ". .bashrc"? Thanks!

Comment: . is a BASH shortcut for the "source" builtin command.  So ". .bashrc" is the same as "source .bashrc" to the BASH interpreter.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Now that I didn't know.

Comment: I just submitted an edit request to add `~/`, but since the top answer shows both `source ~/.bashrc` and `. ~/.bashrc` I wonder if this answer should just be deleted as redundant.

Comment: @RandyProctor: While it's commendable that you point out that your answer is inferior to the accepted one, it would be even better if you simply _deleted_ it, given that it's not only distinctly inferior (due to only working if the current dir. _happens to be_ the current user's home dir., as stated), but, conversely, _adds nothing_ of interest.

Answer (score 26):

With this, you **won't** even have to type "source ~/.bashrc":

**Include your bashrc file:**

```
alias rc="vim ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc"
```

Every time you want to edit your bashrc, just run the alias "**rc**"

Answer (score 20):

Depending on your environment, just typing

```
bash
```

may also work.

Comment: However, this will invoke a new shell within the current one, thus wasting resources. Better use @WhoSayln's [exec](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec) solution which **replaces** the current shell with the newly invoked one.

Comment: yeah just use source. This is entirely unnecessary and annoying.

Comment: In addition to @BernhardWagner's comment, you also loose your current bash history if your spawn a new shell

Comment: This is good solution whereby user privilege access is limited.

Comment: invoking a subprocess adds a layer of complexity that has no additional value.

Answer (score 19):

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

> [`.` is a POSIX-mandated builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot)

---

### Alternatives

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

> [`source` is a synonym for dot/period `.` in bash, but not in POSIX sh, so for maximum compatibility use the period.](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html)

```
exec bash
```

> - `exec` command **replaces the shell** with a given program... – WhoSayIn

Comment: `exec bash` still inherits the environment of the current shell. `exec env -i bash` would be closer (or `exec env -i bash -l` if you are currently in a login shell).

Answer (score 11):

`exec bash` is a great way to re-execute and launch a new shell to replace current. just to add to the answer, `$SHELL` returns the current shell which is bash. By using the following, it will reload the current shell, and not only to bash.

```
exec $SHELL -l;
```

Comment: Just to state it explicitly: `$SHELL` reflects the current user's _default shell_, so this is a way to replace the current session - whatever shell's process it may be - with a new session of the user's default shell. `-l` makes the new session a _login_ session, which is appropriate on macOS (and by default only loads `~/.bash_profile`, not also `~/.bashrc`), but not on Linux.

Answer (score 10):

I used easyengine to set up my vultr cloud based server.
I found my bash file at `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

So `source /etc/bash.bashrc` did the trick for me!

**update**

When setting up a bare server (ubuntu 16.04), you can use the above info, when you have not yet set up a username, and are logging in via *root*.

It's best [to create a user (with sudo privileges)](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-ubuntu/), and login as this username instead.
This will create a directory for your settings, including `.profile` and `.bashrc` files as described on the previous ressource.

Now, you will edit and (and `source`) the `~/.bashrc` file.

On my server, this was located at `/home/your_username/.bashrc`
(where `your_username` is actually the new username you created above, and now login with)

Answer (score 6):

Depending upon your environment, you may want to add scripting to have `.bashrc` load automatically when you open an SSH session. I recently did a migration to a server running Ubuntu, and there, `.profile`, not `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` is loaded by default. To run any scripts in `.bashrc`, I had to run `source ~/.bashrc` every time a session was opened, which doesn't help when running remote deploys.

To have your `.bashrc` load automatically when opening a session, try adding this to `.profile`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Reopen your session, and it should load any paths/scripts you have in `.bashrc`.

Comment: I have this in ".profile" but it's not working — each time I exit, I have to do it by hand. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

For me what works when I change the PATH is: `exec "$BASH" --login`

Comment: The question is about reloading `~/.bashrc`, which `--login` will _not_ (directly) reload; at a user level, it'll reload `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

i use the following command on msysgit

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

shorter version of

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: @jwg the accepted answer is . .bashrc . will work only if you are in the home directory on msysgit.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an interactive shell, and you'd like to keep your current command history and also load /etc/profile (which loads environment data including /etc/bashrc and on Mac OS X loads paths defined in /etc/paths.d/ via path_helper), append your command history and do an exec of bash with the login ('-l') option:

```
history -a && exec bash -l
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want a shell as after logging out and in again.
I believe the best way to achieve that is:

```
exec env -i HOME="$HOME" "$SHELL" -l
```

`exec` will replace the current shell, such that you are not left with it when the new one exits. `env` will create a new empty environment, with `-i` we add `$HOME` so that your shell (usually bash) given by `$SHELL` can find `~/.profile`/`~/.bash_profile` (and thus (on ubuntu or if specified) `~/.bashrc`). Those will be sourced thanks to `-l`. I'm not completely sure though.

Comment: This works well for e.g. undoing conda init in an interactive LSF job (where you don't want to wait in the LSF queue just for a clean shell)

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of $SHELL may produce unexpected results
for example connected on a Docker environment

```
echo $SHELL
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

so if you try, you will be disconnected

```
exec $SHELL
This account is currently not available.
```

so you may have to use something more complicated like

```
exec $(pgrep -l sh | grep "^`echo $$` " | cut -d" " -f2)
```

assuming that every shell contains "sh", and this command pipeline

```
pgrep -l sh | grep "^`echo $$` " | cut -d" " -f2
```

produces a complete command
if you have arguments or flags you may have to use -f2,3,4
or try

```
pgrep -l sh | grep "^`echo $$` " | sed -E 's/^[0-9]+ //'
```

But read all the advices above
Personally i dont like to loose the shell history... but it's up to you and to your needs

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that pure `exec bash` command will preserve the environment variables, so you need to use `exec -c bash` to run bash in an empty environment.

For example, you login a bash, and `export A=1`, if you `exec bash`, the `A == 1`.

If you `exec -cl bash`, `A` is empty.

I think this is the best way to do your job.

Comment: Is `exec -c` the same as `exec -cl`?

Answer (score 0):

This will also work..

```
cd ~
source .bashrc
```

Comment: It does, but it also changes the working directory to ~, which is not wanted.

Comment: Is it necessary to specify `~` to change the working directory to the user home directory?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a set of scripts I called [bash_magic](https://github.com/jrittenh/bash_magic) that automates this process across numerous shells.  If you update a shell file in the bash magic shell directory (`.bash.d` by default), it will automatically source the update at the next prompt.  So once you've made a change, just hit the `Enter`/`return` key and any updates will be sourced.