# Android command not found even PATH set

Tags: android, sdk

hi i am using ubuntu 12.04. and in ~/.bashrc file I set following things

`export ANDROID_HOME=/home/nilkash/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools`

But still it gives me android: command not found error. how to set path for android. Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: `PATH set` apparently not. post the part relevant to your PATH variable

Answer (score 17):

To include the SDK's tools and platform-tools directories in your PATH environment open text editor to create or modify the **~/.bash_profile** file, adding below line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/nilkash/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/nilkash/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

**For Ubuntu:**

To modify the PATH variable of your system, you need to edit your .bashrc file. To do so, in a terminal, execute the following command:

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

You will now have the Nano text editor enabled on the terminal. Now, at the very top of the file, enter the following:

```
#AndroidDev PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Once you're finished, press CTRL + X, Y, and then hit Enter to save your changes and exit the Nano text editor.

To reload the `~/.bashrc` without re log in:

```
. ~/.bashrc or source ~/.bashrc
```

**References:**
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK)
- [How do I reload .bashrc without logging out and back in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in)

Comment: I tried your solution. I added you line into my bash_profile file. And tried android command on command line but still same error. Why it is so ? Need Help.

Comment: sir I did exactly same. In bashrc file I add those lines after that I close terminal and also start new terminal but still same problem. May I restart mt machine ?

Comment: in bashrc need to add not export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
but
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools

same for platform tools

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, hence up-vote. There are lot of answers on this and other similar questions on this site, like 'define paths' or 'add paths'; but where? only you mentioned that it's in 'bashrc' and also with how to edit it. So request to all to give detailed answer like this. Thanks again.

Comment: Reload `~/.bashrc`: `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` [*details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in)

Answer (score 11):

1) Check in System Settings -> Details, whether your Ubuntu is 32-bit or 64-bit

2) If your Ubuntu is a 32-bit OS then run this `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev` 
In case of 64-bit OS run this `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

3) run this `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk` or better this `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

4) Download SDK platform tools from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

5) Unzip downloaded file "adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030.zip" (you can have a little bit different name ;). But you should get folder contained two sub folder - sdk and eclipse

6) Run this `nautilus ~`

7) In opened window create folder 'android-sdk-linux'

8) copy the all entire contents of folder sdk (from unzipped archive) to this new folder 'android-sdk-linux'

9) try run this `cd ~/android-sdk-linux/tools` then this `./android`. If you did all right you should see Android SDK Manager

10) run this `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` in opened editor add this in very top

```
#AndroidDev PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

11) save and close

12) run `exec bash` then try run `android`

13) give write permissions to android-sdk-linux folder

Enjoy! ;)

Answer (score 4):

> android: command not found error

Solution for Linux and Mac:

1) Export your Android Sdk path to the ANDROID_HOME variable

> $ export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk (where ~/Android/Sdk is a full path to your Sdk folder)

(change "~" to "$HOME" on Mac)

2) Export Sdk tools to the PATH variable

> $ export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

and appended these after the fi
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
    export ANDROID_HOME=/home/dev/Android/Sdk
    export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:ANDROID_HOME/tools
    export JAVA_HOME
    export ANDROID_HOME

and after saving the file

```
exec bash
```

these got my android command working, I had set PATH in .bashrc which was not working for me

Hope It'll help somebody

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables can be defined permanently by editing the `.profile` file in your home directory. Here's how:

Edit your `.profile` file with a command like `gedit ~/.profile`. Append this to the end of the file:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/nilkash/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

You can `source .profile` to make it apply right away. Each time you restart your system, the `.profile` file is loaded, restoring this setting.

OR

This below method works 100% for me on `Ubuntu 12.04`:

- Start the terminal
- $gedit .bashrc
- Add the below line at the enc of the file:

  **PATH=$PATH:/home/nilkash/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/**

**Note:** gedit must be performed only on `.bashrc` and **NOT** on `.bashrc~`

Please do accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I tried your solution. I added above path in my profile file but still same problem. Need Help.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem still exist please make sure that you have the right permissions 
try
    sudo chmod -R 777 /home/your-user-name/.cordova/

Also make sure that you are NOT using sudo to add Android as a platform

This is incorrect in the default Cordova installation
    sudo cordova platform add android

Just do
    cordova platform add android