# CORDOVA : I can't add the android platform on Ubuntu even with PATH modified

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova, platform

[image]
http://pastebin.com/WtZKaEpA

I have this error without the sudo command before

[image]
http://pastebin.com/SVxGXPCX

And this error with the sudo command

Any ideas ?

Comment: Copy actual text; don't paste screenshots, which are hard to read and not searchable.

Comment: @user3265531 show what u have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Such type of error occurs, where there is mismatch in path of your SDK. [Here](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/01/24/how-to-install-cordova-and-phonegap-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-linux/) is good example, which demonstrates, how we use cordova-and-phonegap-on-Ubuntu.

Comment: Just did this but it says that "cordova-3.3.0 is a folder" when I do :
sudo su -c "./cordova* /opt/"

Comment: @user3265531 extract ur cordova zip folder and check it give path to it cd <cordova path> and check it.

Comment: inside there is a bunch of zips and inside those zips are cpp, h files

Comment: @user3265531 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19547471/2522603 check it and let me know

Comment: @user3265531 describe ur steps in ur quest, what u have did and then show the error... than only we can see what r u doing...