# Linux Mint Android SDK Path Issue

Tags: android, linux, path

I'm not able to include the android sdk to my PATH variable, so that I can use "android" from terminal.

I was following this tutorial to enable phonegap (which is my primary goal http://julianhigman.com/blog/2013/10/17/notes-on-setting-up-phonegap-on-ubuntu-for-android-app-development/)

First I took a look at the official android dev page

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio
It says:
"You may want to add android-studio/bin/ to your PATH environmental variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory."

So I extended my .bashrc file with following lines

```
export PATH="/usr/local/android-sdk/android-studio/bin/:$PATH"
```

This points to the correct path as described in on the dev page.
Since this does not work I did some deeper research and found several threads which did not help either.
([Android command not found even PATH set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547201/android-command-not-found-even-path-set))

Most recommend to do the following:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/android-sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools
```

The problem here is, that I dont have any folders named tools or platform tools?

I'm running on Linux mint 16.
If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Update:

echo $PATH results to:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/foo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/android-sdk/tools:/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/android-sdk/android-studio/bin
```

But I added only this line

#### Added to enable android on the path

```
export PATH="/usr/local/android-sdk/android-studio/bin:$PATH"
```

---

Update

Had to install the packages after for android sdk and added them successfully to the .bashrc, now android is available.

---

Thanks in advance

Best

Comment: what you added is the path to the android studio bin, so can launch it. not to be mistaken with the android, adb, and others tools, which sit in `tools` and `platform-tools`. These are under your sdk folder.

Comment: is that for a different purpose then the general "android" command?

Comment: is there such file as `/usr/local/android-sdk/android-studio/bin/android`?

Comment: No, you are right. And I notice I can run studio.sh correctly from cmd now, 
so I guess I installed the wrong package then. 
I will update my question, since this is not a path issue anymore

Comment: you say you want to use `android` from command line. what is it exactly you are trying to acheive ?

Comment: also, tools and platform-tools are probably directly under `/usr/local/android-sdk/`

Comment: @njzk2 I wanted to follow this tutorial

http://julianhigman.com/blog/2013/10/17/notes-on-setting-up-phonegap-on-ubuntu-for-android-app-development/

But it seems I'm confusing things here and have to look for the sdk tools or something like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70592/discussion-between-christoph-ha-and-njzk2).