# Upgrading rsync on OS X using Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, rsync

The `rsync` version on my OS X (10.10.3) is an old one, 2.6.9.  I've tried to upgrade it using Homebrew but I get the following error:

```
Error: No available formula for rsync
```

The new one is supposed to be 3.0+ and much quicker, but how do I install this without deleting the old one?

Comment: You need the dupes formula, but this is off-topic for StackOverflow - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Follow the instructions [here](http://zaiste.net/2012/07/brand_new_rsync_for_osx/):

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install rsync
```

And then edit `/private/etc/paths` to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Edit:

> Warning: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

So, only

```
brew install rsync
```

is enough.

Comment: I got it installed right, and edited my paths correctly but still get rsync --version : 2.6.9 ... any idea why ? (yes, i did restart my terminal)

Comment: @VincentWasteels you can use `which rsync` to view the path to the rsync version that is executing when you call `rsync` or `rsync --version` from the command line.  You can then use `echo $PATH` to look at the order of locations in your PATH variable.  It is possible that `/usr/bin` is still before `/usr/local/bin` in your path.  If so, try examining the contents of the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files to determine where the misordering of directories in your PATH is coming from.

Comment: I experienced the path not initializing as expected but only when doing a remote login to the mac with `ssh`. It was due to how I was connecting (`ssh -t me@mymac caffeinate -i bash`) which started a [non-login shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175). Anyone experiencing problems with the math might want to check their shell - `shopt -q login_shell`. (I suffixed my ssh command with `-l` to fix my problem but that's going off topic a little!)

Comment: When using rsync from another machine to connect to your Mac, use `--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync` so the correct version of the server is used

Comment: I went through the steps outlined above but my version of rsync was still stuck at 2.6.9. I checked `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` for proper paths and things looked correct. Even after opening/closing terminal, the version was still stuck. Finally, I just re-sourced the `/private/etc/paths` file by doing `source /private/etc/paths`. Then checking `rsnych --version` finally showed `3.2.1`. Hope this helps others.

Comment: "Warning: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated."

Comment: rsync now part of homebrew-core. `brew install rsync` now installs without the need for tap.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge my ordering seems to be as you suggested but I still can't use it. Look: `/Users/me/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/me/bin`. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @CharlieParker Just seeing the output that you've given there doesn't reveal that much information.  The key is that you want to look in those different directories.  My suspicion is that one fo the earlier directories in your list will have an earlier version of rsync.  In particular, I'd try checking that very first directory in your list.  It's also possible you somehow have a home-brew configuration that is installing in a different directory than `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge is the issue that my `PATH` has things in an odd order? What is the order that they usually are in mac os X?

Comment: @CharlieParker I'd recommend navigating to the different folders in the path to see if you can identify an earlier version of rsync in them.  You can dot hat with the `cd` command in terminal or the go to folder command within Finder.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge yea I did check that :p. Anyway, it seems that the version `3.1.3` is on the first one in my path `/usr/local/bin` however, its executing the one in the later one i.e. the one on `/usr/bin` which is version `2.6.9`. Thats rather odd...Do you know whats going on? Or what you'd suggest me to make this work?

Comment: @CharlieParker I'd check for thinks like symlinks in your `/Users/me/...` folder.  If still not there, then maybe post / look for a question focused on the issue of the PATH not behaving as expected for order of programs.  Or, as a blunt measure, you could delete the rsync version in the undesired location.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge don't know what fixed it but now that I've updated to a newer version of the OS, tit seems to be using the right version of rsync.

Comment: @CharlieParker Great, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 20):

Merged answers of `Vaibhav Sagar`, `Paulo Almeida`, `woodenflute`, `Community`, the final solution is (just):

**`brew install rsync`**

Explanation:

- **NOT** need `brew tap homebrew/dupes` for `homebrew/dupes` has been deprecated and merged into build-in `homebrew/core`

  - you can use `brew tap` to find existing `homebrew/core`
- after install, if you are in terminal, you need **refresh terminal**: `source ~/.bashrc`, then can use `rsync --version` to see the new version, otherwise it still show old version

Comment: You are missing the most important step, which is to make sure /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin for the PATH.  If this is not done, merely installing a new version will not necessarily result in it being used by the user!

Comment: I needed to add `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin/` to ~/.zprofile

Answer (score 13):

> Warning: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all
>   its formulae were migrated.

Comment: Good to know.  It appears the solution is now that rsync is part of homebrew-core, and thus `brew install rsync` simply works, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

After I followed the accepted answer, there is still no rsync binary in `/usr/local/bin`.

To finally make it work, I had to do the following:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rsync/3.2.3/bin/rsync /usr/local/bin/rsync
source ~/.bashrc
```

In my case, `brew install` installed version rsync 3.2.3.

Comment: This answer deserves more attention.  You might also need to `source ~/.zshrc` to get your `rsync --version` to show you the version homebrew just installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you followed @Vaibhav Sagar's instruction, and checked that everything is correct as per @Michael Ohlrogge's comment and it still doesn't work, try reloading bash as per this answer: [How do I reload .bashrc without logging out and back in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in) by executing
`. ~/.bashrc` or `exec bash`.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem, try to update homebrew

```
brew update
brew update
brew tap home-brew/dupes
brew install rsync
```