# linux: how to execute profile file

Tags: linux, user-profile

My colleague gave me a file containing lots of configs such as

```
alias  ll="ls -l"
alias  lr="ls -lrt"
alias  gv="vim -g"
```

How can I use(execute) this profile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reload .bashrc without logging out and back in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can load the profile using **source** command:

```
source <profile-filename>
```

eg:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

For your custom aliases, the best place should be at ~/.bash_aliases. You must just be sure the ~/.bashrc file already contains the following lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

or in a more concise manner:

```
[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ] && . ~/.bash_aliases
```

To load them immediately, source it. Otherwise, aliases will be loaded at every terminal opening. To check, use the alias command without argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in your local .bashrc (or appropriate shell rc file) file if you want it permanently.

```
cat fileNameProfile >> ~/.bashrc
```

And for current session:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If you want it just now, then:

```
source fileNameProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

For one time use, copy paste commands to your terminal:-

```
alias  ll="ls -l"
alias  lr="ls -lrt"
alias  gv="vim -g"
```

For everytime use, add it in .bashrc.

```
echo 'alias  ll="ls -l"' >>  ~/.bashrc
echo 'alias  lr="ls -lrt"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'alias  gv="vim -g"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and then `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

To autoload these alias commands, create a *.sample_profile* file and add the alias on the file.
after that add this text in *.bashrc* file

**.bashrc**

```
if [ -f ~/.sample_profile ]; then
    . ~/.sample_profile
fi
```