# Configuring the software SLEPc - issue setting environmental variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, configure

Can anyone help me set the environmental variables for configuring the software [SLEPc](http://slepc.upv.es/documentation/instal.htm) (a library for the solution of large sparse eigenproblems on parallel computers). I am using in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have used [petsc-3.2 Docs: Installation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html) and [PETSc Documentation: Installation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.2/docs/installation.html) pages as a guideline, where it states:

specify enviornment variable for `csh/tcsh` [can be specified in `~/.cshrc`]

```
setenv PETSC_DIR /home/balay/petsc-3.7.0
setenv PETSC_ARCH linux-gnu-c-debug
```

specify enviornment variable for `bash` [can be specified in `~/.bashrc`]

```
export PETSC_DIR=/home/balay/petsc-3.7.0
export PETSC_ARCH=linux-gnu-c-debug
```

I get error message:

```
$ ./configure
Checking environment...
ERROR: PETSC_DIR enviroment variable is not set
```

I have added to the end of my `~/.bashrc` file the following:

```
export SLEPC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/slepc/slepc
export PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc
export PETSC_ARCH=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug
```

and to my `~/.cshrc` file:

```
setenv SLEPC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/slepc/slepc
setenv PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc
setenv PETSC_ARCH=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug
```

Comment: If the './configure' is a bash can you run 'bash -x ./configure' and show us the output. Also please show us the outpout of 'env|egrep PETSC_DIR '

Comment: ...that said, testing would indeed be useful. `declare -p PETSC_DIR` will show both the value for the variable *and* whether it's exported (`declare -x PETSC_DIR=...` indicates that it's exported; `declare -- PETSC_DIR=...` indicates otherwise).

Comment: @Aleks, this particular `configure` script isn't written in a shell language at all, so `bash -x configure` won't be helpful. See https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc/src/dcd36c237939d4bae4c670048cc3c33706a8123f/configure?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: I have the following outputs:
`$ bash -x ./configure
+ import sys
./configure: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token ('
./configure: line 4: `if not type(sys.version_info) is tuple and sys.version_info.major > 2:'

$ env|egrep PETSC_DIR`
PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc`

Comment: 'import sys' looks to a python script for me. what'st the shebang line, that's the first lines of the script. What's the ouput of 'egrep PETSC_DIR ./configure'. It looks to me that the python script './configure' does not recognize that env var. What does the SLEPc guys mean to your problem?

Comment: I'm working on setting up MIT image reconstruction software, using the forward and inverse solvers @ [MIT_Inverse](https://github.com/rosskynch/MIT_Inverse) . It requires [finite element meshing code - dealii](http://www.dealii.org/8.4.1/readme.html) to run; that includes most of the 'Optional interfaces to other software packages' on this page. I contacted the author and he said most of them are straight forward to install but some of them are difficult such as PETSc, I think he meant SLEPc.

Answer (score 2):

`~/.bashrc` is the wrong place to configure environment variables -- it's sourced for non-login interactive shells. However, if your platform is MacOS, each Terminal instance starts a *login* shell, so it sources `~/.bash_profile`, not `~/.bashrc`. (You might want to create a `~/.bash_profile` that sources `~/.bashrc` when done, if on such a platform).

Even on more conventional Unix desktops, using `~/.bash_profile` is preferable for environment variables -- it's run *only once* when you log in there, vs on every new interactive shell's creation (every new tab/window, etc). Because environment variables are inherited by child processes (through the process environment), there's no need to export them more than once per process tree.

---

By the way -- reading through [the relevant `configure` script](https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc/src/d24caab14e29d890d97b19b2c7aadd37e4d931ee/config/configure.py?at=v3.2&fileviewer=file-view-default), it appears to *actually* be reading `PETSC_DIR` and `PETSC_ARCH` off the configure script's command line, *not* from the environment. Running `./configure PETSC_DIR="$PETSC_DIR" PETSC_ARCH="$PETSC_ARCH"` is thus liable to be helpful.

Passing a fully-qualified path, when that's what you've used successfully in the past, is likewise liable to be helpful.

Comment: I have removed the code from ~/.bashrc and ~/.cshrc and exported the directories to ~/.bash_profile, with the new output:......
`$ ./configure PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc PETSC_ARCH=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug
ERROR: Invalid arguments PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc PETSC_ARCH=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug
Use -h for help`

Comment: the vars should be before the script. 'PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc PETSC_ARCH=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc/arch-linux2‌​-c-debug ./configure'

Comment: @Aleks, actually, no, the advice to put them on the command line rather than in the environment was deliberate. See the code at https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc/src/ae618e6989482e576d696b8985b6d772300e3607/config/configure.py?at=v3.7&fileviewer=file-view-default#configure.py-48, which is looking for `PETSC_ARCH=` **on `sys.argv`**, not in the environment. (Both autoconf-generated configure scripts and traditional Makefiles accept overrides this way, so it's not a huge surprise to see it implemented here).

Comment: ...the error message referencing the environment is thus surprising, but... well, this doesn't give the appearance of being particularly well-engineered software.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. PETSC_DIR should be on env https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc/src/ae618e6989482e576d696b8985b6d772300e3607/config/configure.py?at=v3.7&fileviewer=file-view-default#configure.py-340 how about to run something like this 'PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc ./configure PETSC_ARCH=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc/arch-linux2‌​-c-debug'

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the `setenv` code in `~/.cshrc` and added to the end of `~/.bashrc` file the following:

```
export SLEPC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/slepc/slepc
export PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc
export PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug
```

I then entered `source ~/.bashrc` to [reload .bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in) and:

```
$ ./configure PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc PETSC_ARCH=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug
```

gives:

```
ERROR: Invalid arguments PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc PETSC_ARCH=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug
Use -h for help
```

So then I tried `./configure` only. It gives:

```
$ ./configure
Checking environment... done
Checking PETSc installation... done
Checking LAPACK library... done
Writing various configuration files... done
Generating Fortran stubs... done

===============================================================================
SLEPc Configuration
===============================================================================

SLEPc directory:
 /home/brendan/Documents/slepc/slepc
  It is a git repository on branch: master
PETSc directory:
 /home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc
  It is a git repository on branch: master
Architecture "arch-linux2-c-debug" with double precision real numbers

xxx=========================================================================xxx
 Configure stage complete. Now build the SLEPc library with (gnumake build):
   make SLEPC_DIR=$PWD PETSC_DIR=/home/brendan/Documents/petsc_2/petsc PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug
xxx=========================================================================xxx
```

I think the `source ~/.bashrc` worked with `./configure` !