# Can't access correct application default credentials for Dialogflow app

Tags: credentials, dialogflow-es, google-cloud-node

I have created a Dialogflow agent with a concurrent gcloud app. However, when I try to integrate it into a Node.js backend, it seems to be accessing the wrong application default credentials.

I can confirm that it is verifying authentication is successful because it console logs the correct project ID (diagnosistest-56e81) when I run this code:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library.
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')

// Instantiates a client. If you don't specify credentials when constructing
// the client, the client library will look for credentials in the
// environment.
const storage = new Storage();

// Makes an authenticated API request.
storage
  .getBuckets()
  .then((results) => {
    const buckets = results[0];

    console.log('Buckets:');
    buckets.forEach((bucket) => {
      console.log(bucket.name);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  })
```

However, when I try to connect dialogflow, I get an error.

Code to connect to dialogflow:

```
// You can find your project ID in your Dialogflow agent settings
const projectId = 'diagnosistest-56e81'; //https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents#settings
const sessionId = 'quickstart-session-id';
const query = 'hello';
const languageCode = 'en-US';

// Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

// Define session path
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

// The text query request.
const request = {
  session: sessionPath,
  queryInput: {
    text: {
      text: query,
      languageCode: languageCode,
    },
  },
};

// Send request and log result
sessionClient
  .detectIntent(request)
  .then(responses => {
    console.log('Detected intent');
    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
    console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
    if (result.intent) {
      console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Error message that I receive:

```
ERROR: { Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Dialogflow API has not been used in project 764086051850 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dialogflow.googleapis.com/overview?project=764086051850 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

The weird thing is, my project number is 889800549397 and not 764086051850. So it seems like it's not accessing the correct credentials.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Create new Dialogflow service account key and setting export to the json key file via `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/Users/Joseph/workspace/finddoc/DiagnosisTest-cred.json`
2. Deleting `application_default_credentials.json` file in `./config/gcloud/` folder.

When I do this I get a different error message:

```
ERROR: Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out what the problem was. After setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, you have to restart your computer so it can take effect!

Comment: Where have you exported GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS? I have followed this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-python) and could access using json key without restart (I did it via Gcloud Shell)

Comment: Actually i included it in my .bash_profile like so. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = [path]`. It seemed like if I just typed the command in terminal then it wouldn't set it as an environment variable permanently. I also followed the same tutorial as you

Comment: OK. Agree that the environment variable won't be permanent if executed in terminal. I understood that it is not working for you when run the command in the terminal. Just to add some notes, I think it is not necessary to restart the machine, you can reload the .bash_profile file with EXEC command as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in/9584378#9584378)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this exact same error message (including 764086051850 project id) on my local machine when trying to use the Dialogflow V2 API. I didn't want to bother with the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable so I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login).

Specifically, this section was important:

> API enablement and quotas are managed by the master Application Default Credentials project. In the case of errors related to the API not being enabled or quota limitations, use the --client-id-file flag. You can create the client-id-file at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials.

The command I ended up running:

`gcloud auth application-default login --client-id-file=my_app_client_id.json`

This will save the Application Default Credentials to a file in your home directory. For example: `/Users/nathanb/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`