# How to reset the default python of Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, ros

I have installed miniconda, and I need to use ROS2 now, so I have commented the conda init code in .bashrc file. But if I run `which python` or `which python3` command, the output is still the miniconda python.

```sh
yan@yan-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ which python
/home/yan/miniconda3/bin/python

yan@yan-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ which python3
/home/yan/miniconda3/bin/python3
```

So I tried the following methods.

```sh
yan@yan-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python     /usr/bin/python3.8           /usr/bin/python3-coverage    /usr/bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script3
/usr/bin/python2    /usr/bin/python3.8-config    /usr/bin/python3-futurize    /usr/bin/python-argcomplete-tcsh3
/usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3.8-coverage  /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
/usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3-config      /usr/bin/python3-pbr

yan@yan-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.8 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in auto mode

yan@yan-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/bin/python3.8
Nothing to configure.

yan@yan-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ sudo update-alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.8

yan@yan-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ which python3
/home/yan/miniconda3/bin/python3
```

So you can see that when I run `which python3`, it still output the miniconda python.

**So how to reset the python to the system default python?**

Comment: Restart your terminal after commenting the lines or see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518150/2681662

Comment: I have sourced the .bashrc file. This is an operation that must be done, so I didn't write it out.

Comment: I knew, the process I described above is correct, but you can't simply use source. bashrc. You need to restart terminal to work.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check python version on terminal - `python --version`
2. Get root user privileges. On terminal type - `sudo su`
3. Write down the root user password.
4. Execute this command to switch to python 3.6. `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1`
5. Check python version - `python --version`
6. Now all done...

Comment: this doesnt solve the specific problem of the question

Comment: I knew, the process I described above is correct, but you can't simply use source. bashrc. You need to restart terminal to work.